# use image as button in jquery with click effect

Tags: jquery, button

I know syntax for button

```
$("#divId").button();
```

But I want to use image.
I have applied

```
$("img").click(function(){......});
```

It work well but clicking image do not give clicking effect.
How to add clicking effect on image.

Comment: What is clicking effect? Also, are you using jQuery UI? If so, please tag it correctly.

Comment: clicking effect = pressing effect. when I click image, image should go down and come back.

Answer (score 3):

```
<html>

<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function(){


    $(".imgclick").mousedown(function(){


        var mrgtb = parseInt($(this).css("margin-top"));

        var mrglf = parseInt($(this).css("margin-left"));

        mrgtb=mrgtb+3;

        mrglf=mrglf+3;

            $(this).css("margin-top",mrgtb+"px").css("margin-left",mrglf+"px");


    }).mouseup(function(){

        var mrgtb = parseInt($(this).css("margin-top"));

        var mrglf = parseInt($(this).css("margin-left"));

        mrgtb=mrgtb-3;

        mrglf=mrglf-3;

            $(this).css("margin-top",mrgtb+"px").css("margin-left",mrglf+"px");

    }); 

});

</script>

</head>

<body>
<p>Hello</p>

<span>World</span><input id="a" class="imgclick" style="outline: none;" type="image" src="a.jpg" width="30px" height="30px" border="0" >



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you want to get the button effect on image or text. Please download the images from the link below or create your own.

HTML:

```
<a class="button" href="#"><span>Bring world peace</span></a>
```

CSS:

```
.clear { /* generic container (i.e. div) for floating buttons */
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}

a.button {
    background: transparent url('bg_button_a.gif') no-repeat scroll top right;
    color: #444;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font: normal 12px arial, sans-serif;
    height: 24px;
    margin-right: 6px;
    padding-right: 18px; /* sliding doors padding */
    text-decoration: none;
}

a.button span {
    background: transparent url('bg_button_span.gif') no-repeat;
    display: block;
    line-height: 14px;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 18px;
}

a.button:active {
    background-position: bottom right;
    color: #000;
    outline: none; /* hide dotted outline in Firefox */
}

a.button:active span {
    background-position: bottom left;
    padding: 6px 0 4px 18px; /* push text down 1px */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in script tag write blow code for image div and place image tag inside the div
like its done here

$(document).ready(function() {

```
$("#clickimage").click(function(){
    alert("image is clicked");  

});
```

});

```
   <!--<div id="clickimage"><img src="wc.png" width="100" height="100"></div>-->
```

Comment: .click do not add click effect

Comment: what do you really mean for click effect....? above code is working fine when you click on the image it triggers the alert. make me clear about your question.

Comment: upon clicking image should go down and come up... You know button press effect

Answer (score 0):

Below is another simple way to add click effect using mousedown and mouseup events. When margin is modified I observed other controls in the window displace. I have given below a simple solution to get click effect using border.

```
$(".imgclick").mousedown(function () {

    $(this).css("border", "1px solid #ECECEC");

}).mouseup(function () {

    $(this).css("border", "none");
});
```